# Can I add a picture/diagram in a requirement?

Tags: requirements, specification

I got the feedback of my first specification, one of the proofreader commented for clarification on one of the requirements (a concept hard to grasp i admit).

Can I add an explanation and a diagram *in* the requirement to help him?

Comment: What would make you think you can't?

Comment: You should be working in the requirements space instead of the solution space. You are dancing on the line of telling them what to build vs. explaining the need.

Comment: Visual aids can often be helpful, but there's a huge distinction between providing a visual aid for a requirement or specification and creating a UX/UI wireframe. Have you considered asking the proofreaders what they expect to get out of the diagram? More importantly, why are you two shuffling paper rather than *talking* about the requirement with one another?

Comment: We talked about the requirement and he wanted a visual aid explaining a concept introducing it. I'm paying attention to only explain the need and not the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use graphical models to help capture and analyze requirements. Using graphical models can not only be used to communicate the details of a single (or small number) of requirements, but help in the overall analysis and understanding of large sets of requirements for various stakeholders.

Although written in the context of software requirements, [Joy Beatty and Anthony Chen's Visual Models for Software Requirements](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667721) dives into nearly two dozen graphical and tabular models that can be used to support requirements engineering and how these models can be captured and traced to textual requirements. Different models have a different relevance and use to different stakeholders.